# HD Partition inconsistence, windows

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-space

I'm NOT asking about merge or how shrinking....

I'm asking about:
Why I have in *Explorer* and *Total Commander* total Size `70.5GB` or `67.29GB` for **Win7 C:** according to Disk Management  (in top Grid Table) ...

[image]

with *Explorer* of Windows

[image]

But in the **Disk 0** says `96.58GB` for **Win7 C:**?

I was tryinn to shringking and ocurred an error... I close and run again "Disk Management" but the information was not updated.

[image]
[image]

checking with `Diskpart`

[image]

**How solve this without lost my information?**

Comment: Wow that really does not sound good. I would recommend backup all your files immediately. Do not run any application until your files are backed up and quit all background processes too. Start with your most important files.